# How do I really know who is accessing my server?

Tags: networking, server, internet

I've tried to search for a solution but I couldn't... Maybe I didn't search well so it could be that the post is duplicated, so I'm sorry if it's like this.

Well, recently I started using my old desktop computer as a server, I installed Ubuntu server 18.04 and it's now connected to my router. I also have a web page (Only for testing) and a SSH server to login and monitor the server from anywere (obvious) and the problem comes now:

I have the server connected to the router and the router (ADSL) is connected to the internet. I have set up the router to forward any request that wants to connect via port 80 or 22 to the private IP of the server. And now, whenever someone connects to my web server, the access logs shows me that all petitions are coming from the same IP (My public IP) and same with SSH, whenever I connect to my server, when I type the command `who` it shows me I'm connected from my public IP. 
I know that problem it's because it's my router who is forwarding the packaged and requests but I would like to know if there is any kind of "solution" to this so I'm able to actually know who is stablishing a connection to my server.

Thanks in advice and sorry if I misspelled, trying my best to write this correctly.

Output of `who` command:

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ who
alex    pts/0     2019-02-07 07:22 (62.37.40.224)
alex    pts/1     2019-02-07 07:22 (62.37.40.224)
```

[image: logging in with ssh]

Outuput of the `traceroute` command to my server's IP:

```
traceroute to 62.37.40.224 (62.37.40.224), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   192.168.212.254 (192.168.212.254)  3.004 ms  2.972 ms  2.947 ms
   172.29.34.1 (172.29.34.1)  7.755 ms  7.736 ms  7.686 ms
   1.red-81-46-16.customer.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (81.46.16.1)  7.662 ms  7.621 ms  7.584 ms
   217.red-217-124-114.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (217.124.114.217)  15.257 ms 217.124.112.37 (217.124.112.37)  20.113 ms 217.124.114.217 (217.124.114.217)  20.108 ms
   * * *
   157.red-80-58-84.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.84.157)  14.988 ms  15.931 ms  15.895 ms
   145.red-80-58-97.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.97.145)  15.865 ms * *
   80.58.106.58 (80.58.106.58)  14.724 ms  14.712 ms  14.687 ms
   241.red-80-58-88.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.88.241)  14.661 ms  14.635 ms  14.615 ms
  10.21.0.1 (10.21.0.1)  14.565 ms  14.475 ms  20.228 ms
  10.21.0.2 (10.21.0.2)  20.180 ms  20.143 ms  20.111 ms
  172.27.111.22 (172.27.111.22)  15.212 ms  15.175 ms  15.005 ms
  172.27.111.51 (172.27.111.51)  14.931 ms  14.818 ms  14.807 ms
  172.27.111.126 (172.27.111.126)  14.797 ms  14.776 ms  14.762 ms
  172.27.111.10 (172.27.111.10)  19.592 ms  16.708 ms  16.622 ms
  193.152.56.1 (193.152.56.1)  19.503 ms  19.474 ms  19.407 ms
  80.58.72.149 (80.58.72.149)  19.399 ms  19.356 ms  19.292 ms
  * * *
  * * *
  216.184.113.180 (216.184.113.180)  23.230 ms  17.892 ms *
  * * *
  * * *
  * 193.251.247.14 (193.251.247.14)  16.104 ms *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
```

Comment: `Whenever someone connects to my web server, the access logs shows me that all petitions are coming from [...] My public IP` This should not be the case. Are you very sure about this ?

Comment: @RoVo I attached 2 screenshots. In the first 1 I'm logged in to the server with 2 different computers and in the second one you can watch which IP I'm connecting to with the SSH Client

Comment: Are you using your public IP address (and port forwarding) to connect the server? Then it would be the correct behavior. If not, I am suspecting your router maintains two (or more) separate subnets, so your request to the server appears as going from outside. Please [edit] your post to add the output of the command `traceroute <your-server-ip>` to check this. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to the pasted terminal text, please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300).

Comment: you're connecting from the same network ?

Comment: @Melebius I've updated it and added the output of the `traceroute` command. Note that I'm logging in from my univeristy, I'm accessing from a proxy and lots of services don't work (such as `ping`)

Comment: @RoVo I'm not in the same network at the moment

Comment: So it happens when you connect from outside? I thought it happens from the LAN, too. Anyway, this looks related to your router rather than Ubuntu and [su] should be a better place to ask. It might be configurable but you haven’t provided any details of your router yet.

Comment: @Melebius No, when I connect from LAN it shows the private IP, it's only from the outside... Anyways thanks for trying to help, I'll post in Super User now and what details can I provide from my router in order to get some help?

Comment: Reposted on [su] as https://superuser.com/questions/1403052/how-do-i-really-know-who-is-accessing-my-server.

Comment: @Melebius Huawei HG532s